# What does $\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})$ mean?

Tags: trigonometry, notation, angle

Here $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three angles of a triangle, so $A+B+C=\pi$. Now, my book did the following:

$$\cos A$$

$$=\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})\tag{1}$$

$$=-\cos(B+C)$$

**My comments:**

In $\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})$, there seems to be no special meaning to the overline to me. $\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})$ and $\cos(\pi-(B+C))$ seem to be equal. In other words, to me the following seems to be true:

$$\cos(\pi-\overline{B+C})=\cos(\pi-(B+C))$$

So, why did my book put the overline symbol over $B+C$? What meaning does it hold?

**My question:**

1. What meaning does the overline symbol hold in $(1)$?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.It means ( ) .

Comment: We can only guess, this is not a standard notation. I suspect you need to flip through the pages of your book to find the meaning explained somewhere.

Comment: The author maybe thinks it looks clearer. Nested brackets are not the most readable sometimes.

Comment: I think they used it for complement of $B+C,$ but it is mistaken, because $A=\pi-({B+C}),$ while $\pi-\overline{B+C}=B+C$ in a triangle.

Comment: This horizontal bar is used in textbooks dating from the end of the 19th century. It is as you surmised the same thing as parentheses.

Comment: @BernardMasse If you name a textbook example you could just post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @Mark S. For an example of the bar being used as a pair or parentheses, see for example p.397 of Cajori, F. A History of Mathematical Notations, Dover 1993 which seems to be a reprint of the 1928 edition. If pages are changed, look for article 353. Contrary to what I wrote, it is rather used in the 17th and 18th centuries although it could have existed longer than that.

Comment: @BernardMasse if you post this comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example of the bar being used as a pair or parentheses, see for example p.397 of Cajori, F. A History of Mathematical Notations, Dover 1993 which seems to be a reprint of the 1928 edition. If pages are changed, look for article 353. Contrary to what I wrote, it is rather used in the 17th and 18th centuries although it could have existed longer than that.